# Count of total unread messages

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, chat

In my flutter & firebase app, I use cloud functions to send notifications for any new messages. The problem I face is how I show count of total unread messages in the chatroom list tile as shown in red circles in this famous chat app.
[image]

My chatroom page looks almost like this picture except for the unread message counter at the right side of each tile. What logic do I have to use?
Please give me any advice to implement showing count of unread messages at the right side of each chatroom tile.
Here is my chatroom collection in firestore.
[image][image]

Comment: what is your DB structure?

Comment: @ BloodLoss I added screenshots of my firestore collection, I have `chatroom` and `crews(users)` collection there.

Comment: you have one `document` in `chatRoom`. what is this meaning?

Comment: @ BloodLoss I am just experimenting with 1 chatroom document now. I can add as many as I need or want.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add 3 more fields in the document:-

1. 1stpersonMessageCount
2. 2ndPersonMessageCount
3. MessageCount

So now what you need to do is that in your chatting screen you simply need to increment the message count of the person who is sending the message everytime he send the message:-

```
chatRoomReference.updateData({
                      "messageCount":FieldValue.increment(1),
                      "${currentUser}messageCount":FieldValue.increment(1),
                    });
```

and for message seen purpose you can simply update the messagecount of reciever by

```
    chatRoomReference.updateData({
                      "${currentUser}messageCount":snapshot.documents.length,
                    });
```

and on the page where you want to see the count of new messages you simply subtract the value of messageCount and cureentUserMessageCount.

In both the code sections you can see that currentUser is there bt don't get confused when the sender is sending the message then currentUser's value would be the sender's name or his id and when someone is reading then his id or name. Ex- John is sending then current User will be John and when mohan is reading the message then it would be mohan. Hence you will have 3 fields i.e. JohnMessageCount, MohanMessageCount and total messages i.e. messageCount.

Comment: have updated my code you need to increment the sender's count and total count by 1 and update the reciever's count as the length of documents or total documents when you load them from firebase on chat page.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but my count doesn't add up, only showing number 1. I edited my question with the picture. Please take a look.

Comment: can you tell what is the value of currentUser you are having in the code. I think it is an empty string. You shall create a variable currentUser and either assign the current user's id or username to it . Then it will work

Comment: Suppose John's msgCount is 10, Mohan's msgCount is 10, totaling 20, and John sends a message. Then, John's msgCount will be 11, Mohan's msgCount is 10, totaling 21. According to your logic, on Mohan's device, the number of unread msg will be 21-10?

Comment: yes it will be 21-10 and as soon as mohan see's the message it will be 21-21

Comment: it will be 21-10 only if mohan have not seen the 11 messages of john i.e. mohan wrote 10 msg then john sent 11 and mohan ain't have seen them and as soon as he have read those then mohan count will increase to 21 (10 sent by him and 11 read) this 21-21

Comment: What if Mohan read all the previous messages, and didn't read this 1 new message, how do you calculate to show 1 as a result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228341/discussion-between-deepak-lohmod-and-kyung).